# admob server side verification test verify doesn't send reward_amount

Tags: admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

When setting up rewarded ads on Admob, when I click on `VERIFY URL` on the Admob's rewarded ads settings, I noticed that in my server side application it doesn't receive the `reward_amount` query parameter while all the other parameters are received.

Apparently google doesn't send this parameter in this situation.

I need this value to test if my implementation is fine.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: update your question with code to review